# Change value of range slider dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, html-input

I have some divs with an `input[type="text"]` and an input[type="range"] inside.

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="10">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="18" step="1">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="10">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="18" step="1">
</div>
```

With the help of some jQuery the range sliders have uneven steps and the value of the text input fields change while moving the slider.

If you enter a number in an input field, the number changes to the nearest step/value.

```
stepVal = [10, 35, 50, 90, 100, 135, 155, 170, 190, 220, 230, 250, 270, 290, 310, 320, 350, 365, 400];
$('.box').each(function() {
  $(this).on('input', 'input[type="range"]', function() {
    $(this).prev('input[type=text]').val(stepVal[this.value]);
  });
  $(this).on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    var closestVal = stepVal.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - textVal) < Math.abs(prev - textVal) ? curr : prev);
    });
    $(this).val(closestVal);
    $(this).next('input[type=range]').val(closestVal);
  });
});
```

The problem is that the range slider moves only to the end or to the middle but not to the entered step/value. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the wrong `value` to the `range`, when you enter a `value` in the input text.

Because you are setting the value to the `closestVal` while it should be the respective `index` of `closestVal`, that's why it gets only to the middle when `closestValue` is `10` and to the end for other values which are higher than the `max`.

**Solution:**

You need to change this:

```
$(this).next('input[type=range]').val(closestVal);
```

To get the index of this value from your `stepVal` array, when you enter a value in the `input`.

```
$(this).next('input[type=range]').val(stepVal.indexOf(closestVal));
```

**Demo:**

```js
stepVal = [10, 35, 50, 90, 100, 135, 155, 170, 190, 220, 230, 250, 270, 290, 310, 320, 350, 365, 400];
$('.box').each(function() {
  $(this).on('input', 'input[type="range"]', function() {
    $(this).prev('input[type=text]').val(stepVal[this.value]);
  });
  $(this).on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    var closestVal = stepVal.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - textVal) < Math.abs(prev - textVal) ? curr : prev);
    });
    $(this).val(closestVal);
    $(this).next('input[type=range]').val(stepVal.indexOf(closestVal));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="10">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="18" step="1">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" value="10">
    <input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="18" step="1">
</div>
```

Comment: There's a little error in your code snippet » missing ) but you're right, that's the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @stewe1da It was just a copy/paste typo ;)